# Conflicts between jQuery and Prototype

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, prototypejs, conflict

I am building a rails application and installing this gem called "best-in-place" for one-time editing. It was working for a while, but after I struggled with jQuery and Prototype conflicts, it stopped working and now I get this error message when trying to load the page.

[error http://dl.getdropbox.com/u/3481269/Screen%20shot%202011-04-30%20at%206.17.45%20PM.png](http://dl.getdropbox.com/u/3481269/Screen%20shot%202011-04-30%20at%206.17.45%20PM.png)

I am including both the jQuery and prototype JS files.

```
    <script src="/javascripts/jquery.js?1303396383" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="/javascripts/rails.js?1303562965" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="/javascripts/application.js?1303842064" type="text/javascript"></script> 

    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"> 
        $j = jQuery.noConflict();
    </script> 

    <script src="/javascripts/prototype.js?1303686720" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="/javascripts/jquery.purr.js?1302145859" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="/javascripts/best_in_place.js?1302150372" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Can you help me trouble-shoot what might be the cause for this error?

Answer (score 4):

You are assigning the jQuery `.noConflict()` method to `$j` so for jQuery stuff you must now use `$j` not `$` so for instance `$j(document).ready(...`

Comment: He can also use `jQuery` rather than `$`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that the best-in-place plugin is for jQuery, so forgive the rest of this if I'm mistaken. Unless you have written a ton of JS that depends on Prototype in your app, I'd probably ditch it in favor of jQuery. It's [pretty easy](https://github.com/indirect/jquery-rails) to make the switch.

Even though it's possible to use both with proper namespacing, it's not worth it. There's a massive amount of overlap between the two, and you're adding a lot of extra weight to your code. One JavaScript framework should be enough for one page! :)

Comment: one dom library you mean. neither jquery or prototype are really frameworks